# undeclared navigation object?

Tags: iphone, navigation

already i am declared navigation object like this

```
UINavigationController *naviButtonpro;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *naviButtonpro;
```

and also declared @synthesize naviButtonpro;

```
self.naviButtonpro = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NaviButtonViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.window addSubview:self.naviButtonpro.view];
```

when i am using this method

```
-(IBAction)displayNextPage:(id)sender
{
    dispNext *gotoback = [[dispNext alloc] initWithNibName:@"dispNextView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    //UINavigationController *naviButtonpro = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NaviButtonViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.naviButtonpro pushViewController:gotoback animated:YES];
    [gotoback release];
}
```

i am geting an error like this 
Request for member 'naviButtonpro' in something not a structure or union

can u tell me the how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things to note here.

Firstly, you aren't creating a UINavigationController. You need to alloc init it. You seem to have it in the code but its commented out.

Secondly, dispNext needs to subclass & inherit from UIViewController. Does it do this?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is where you are initializing the 'naviButtonpro' and second is
What kind of the class its inherited of your interface class ? is it UIView or UIViewController.